# Securing an Impact Factor rating for a journal

Tags: publications, peer-review, impact-factor

What's the process to secure an Impact Factor rating for a journal?

I am taking over a journal which has been published for 10 years (2 editions a year) and has a wide readership, albeit in a specialist area. I am hoping that by getting a rating we can improve the quality of submissions. The journal is English language, business related and peer reviewed with a strong international editorial board of established academics.

Comment: Are you taking over as Editor in Chief? If the journal has served for 10 years, then it must have an impact factor? How much is it at the present? Kindly, provide some information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The necessary information is available in the Clarivate Analytics website, which is the official body which calculates and publishes impact factors. The info is based on their citation indexes, which were originally developed by Thomson Reuters.

Information on the journal selection process:
http://wokinfo.com/essays/journal-selection-process/

Journal submission form:
http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/info/journalsubmission-front/

Other relevant information on impact factors:
http://wokinfo.com/essays/impact-factor/